# From contingency tables to data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, contingency

My starting point is having several character vectors containing POS tags I extracted from texts. For example:

```
c("NNS", "VBP", "JJ",  "CC",  "DT")
c("NNS", "PRP", "JJ",  "RB",  "VB")
```

I use `table()` or `ftable()` to count the occurences of each tag.

```
 CC  DT  JJ NNS VBP 
 1   1   1   1   1
```

The ultimate goal is to have a data.frame looking like this:

```
   NNS VBP PRP JJ CC RB DT VB
1  1   1   0   1  1  0  1  0
2  1   0   1   1  0  1  0  1
```

Using `plyr::rbind.fill` seems reasonable to me here, but it needs data.frame objects as inputs. However, when using `as.data.frame.matrix(table(POS_vector))` an error occurs.

```
Error in seq_len(ncols) : 
argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
```

Using `as.data.frame.matrix(ftable(POS_vector))` actually produces a data.frame, but without the colnames.

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 ...
1  1  1  1  1
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you can try:

```
table(rev(stack(setNames(dat, seq_along(dat)))))
```

You can also use `mtabulate` from "qdapTools":

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(dat)
#   CC DT JJ NNS PRP RB VB VBP
# 1  1  1  1   1   0  0  0   1
# 2  0  0  1   1   1  1  1   0
```

`dat` is the same as defined in @Heroka's answer:

```
dat <- list(c("NNS", "VBP", "JJ",  "CC",  "DT"),
            c("NNS", "PRP", "JJ",  "RB",  "VB"))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the quick help guys.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bit of a workaround, but this might be a solution.

We assume all our vectors are in a list:

```
dat <- list(c("NNS", "VBP", "JJ",  "CC",  "DT"),
c("NNS", "PRP", "JJ",  "RB",  "VB"))
```

Then we transform our table to a transposed matrix, which we convert to a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
temp <- lapply(dat,function(x){
  data.table(t(as.matrix(table(x))))
})
```

Then we use `rbindlist` to create the desired output:

```
rbindlist(temp,fill=T)
```

We can also choose to put all our data in a data.table first, and then do the aggregating. Note that this assumes equal vector lengths.

```
temp <- as.data.table(dat)
#turn to long format
temp_m <- melt(temp, measure.vars=colnames(temp))

#count values for each variable/value-combination, then reshape to wide
res <- dcast(temp_m[,.N,by=.(variable,value)], variable~value,value.var="N", fill=0)
```

Comment: Very elegant. Would you consider adding this to your answer?